# How to convert Date into Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a one filter where user can put any date manually.

Requirement is if a user enters date as **3/2/2012** it should come in **2 mar or 2-march** (in text any format).

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom Formatting for the cell and use the following format.

```
dd-mmm
```

Comment: As i am new to excel, can you tell me in more detail. I am using pivot table and Data both. So tell me  in concern with Pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to present it that way: Right click -> Format  Cells -> Date

If you want to transform the date in text inside the spreadsheet: =text(datecell,"dd mmm")

If you are doing in VBA: cell.Value = format(cell.Value, "dd mmm") (didnt try this one.. but it is something like that - check the format function reference)

Comment: Thanks Michael. I let you know after applying both methods.

Comment: Now my question is in my dynamic report. I made it in same sheet where is my Pivot table. I have Date column. Whatever date I selected in pivot table it is coming in that column.                                     Is It possible user can type there date and whole data will be refreshed.